# make value of a function global to be called in any other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i want to pass the value of a function to any other function or make the value of a function global so that it can be called in any other function . but i dnt knw how to do it , tried some codes still no sucess .

here is the function code

```
function newalbum(val1,loginuser)
{

$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: 'ajax/album.php?val='+val1+'&& loguser='+loginuser,
success: function(data) {
$("#newalbum1").html(data);
        var ab=$('#ab').val();
        var abc=$('#loginuser').val();
        var action=$('#action').val();

alert(ab);
}
});
}
```

in this function i want to make the three variables var ab, var abc, var action to be global so that its value can be used in any other function . can any one help?

edit - the value of var ab, var abc, and var action is comming from ajax data that is why i am not able to use those variable directly , it says undefined if i use it directly.

after the varibales value received from ajax in function newalbum . i want to use those   varibales inside

```
 (function( $ ){
 $.fn.Uploadrr = function( options ) {
```

Comment: Sakshi why dont you declare ab abc and action outside the function and assigning them values inside????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the variables in the global scope, and remove `var` before the `ab`, `abc` and `action` variables. Another method is to prefix the variables with `window`, the global object.

Method 1:

```
var ab, abc, action; // In the global scope
...
    ab = ...;        // Inside the function
```

Method 2:

```
window.ab = $('#ab').val(); // Inside the function
```

Note: Unless you've got an extremely good reason for it, you usually should not declare global variables.

Comment: cant they be declared such that i have to use the function name with the variable to call them in another function? var ab,var abc , var action value is comming from ajax data thats why m not able to use those variable outside

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you rephrase it?

Comment: sry , but m not able to get the value of variable in another function . i want to use the value inside (function( $ ){
$.fn.Uploadrr = function( options ) {

Comment: the value of the 3 variables is coming from the ajax . and when the ajax is called then only the value is received  . so i cant declare the variables directly as without calling ajax it cant be used . so i want to call the ajax and get the values in one function and then use those variables in another function .

Comment: @SakshiSharma If I understand correctly, you want to send the data from the AJAX call to another function? If that's the case, you can directly invoke the function with the given data: `function_name(data);`.

Comment: yes i want that. u understood it correctly . please if possible can u explain with a example?

Comment: thanks a lot friend , thanks , i have been searching for a solution from whole day , u saved my day . :)

Comment: hey friend how to use function name such as of this kind ? (function( $ ){
 $.fn.Uploadrr = function( options ) {  instead of the eg u gave function function_name

Comment: `$.fn.Uploadrr` is a jQuery plugin. This method is available on any jQuery object, so `$().Uploadrr(data);`.

Comment: thanks a ton @RobW a perfect explanation and its working . thanks a lot . if thr would have been 100 votes up, i would have def voted up all of em . :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using those variables by making them global why don't you use directly `$('#ab').val()`, `$('#loginuser').val()` and `('#action').val()`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call "var" before starting a new var it'll address a new place in memory. So just start the vars outside the functions and access them inside like this:

```
var ab, abc, action;

function newalbum(val1,loginuser)
{

$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: 'ajax/album.php?val='+val1+'&& loguser='+loginuser,
success: function(data) {
$("#newalbum1").html(data);
        ab=$('#ab').val();
        abc=$('#loginuser').val();
        action=$('#action').val();

alert(ab);
}
});
}
```